# 2d geometry : angle+power prediction for shot

Tags: artificial-intelligence, angle, prediction

before any talking, please look at this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQDAC.jpg

I want to know how can predict right angle and power for ai to make shot meet player . both of them have static position and doesn't move .

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to take a look at [horizontal projectiles](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-2/Horizontally-Launched-Projectiles-Problem-Solving) for starters. The problem is that different power will require different angles of launch, so you would need to try out various power ranges or angle ranges.

EDIT: The image you have attached describes the path of a given projectile (bullet, bomb, any item you throw) across a horizontal plane (parallel to the ground). These particular type of problems usually require a variation of the equations of linear motion which is what you have there on the website.

Besides the equations of motion, the website I linked should give you some simple problems and how you can solve them to make sure that you are following.

As per your question, the targets will be static thus the `distance` component of the equation will be known and will not change. The other components you will need to find is the angle of launch and the initial velocity of the round (denoted by the power you use).

An approach would be to take a range of angles `[1,89]` degree inclusive and see what initial velocity you would need to make the projectile travel `distance`.

If you will be dealing with situations identical to the image, that is, there will be no obstacles in the middle, you can also assume that the angle of launch will always be 45 degrees since that will always give you the maximum range for a constant initial velocity. If you take this approach you will simply need to find the initial velocity require to make a projectile travel `distance` at an angle of 45 degrees.

Comment: A bit more explain and  i appreciate you my friend. this page make me more confused !!!

Comment: @LittleElite: I have updated my answer. This is an entire physics topic so I can only explain so much on this website. Alternatively, you could ask on the physics stack exchange for more information.

Comment: I got it, thanks. my angle is changing each turn but it's not a problem now.